# Elasticsearch index array of made up of another class

Tags: scala, elasticsearch, elastic4s

I have a class which I want to begin indexing into ElasticSearch using the Scala client elastic4s. I have extended DocumentMap to allow me to insert the documents. The simple values like String, Int etc are working but I cannot seem to get a List of another class to map correctly.

The documents look similar to this:

```
case class AThing(UserName: String, Comment: String, Time: String) 
extends  DocumentMap { 
  override def map: Map[String, Any] = Map(
   "UserName" -> UserName,
   "Comment" -> Comment,
   "Time" -> Time
  )
}

case class ThingsThatHappened(Id: String, Things: Seq[AThing] = Nil) 
extends DocumentMap {
  override def map: Map[String, Any] = Map(
    "Id" -> Id,
    "Things" ->  Things
  )
}
```

It will map the Id field fine within elasticsearch but then I get a an incorrect value which looks similar to this, when the document is inserted into elasticsearch:

```
List(AThing(id_for_the_thing,user_name_a,typed_in_comment,2015-03-12))
```

Obviously this is wrong and I am expecting something a kin to this JSON structure once it has been inserted into elasticsearch, such as:

```
"events" : [
   {
     "UserName" :"user_name_a", 
     "Comment": "typed_in_comment", 
     "Time": "2015-03-12"
   }
]
```

Does anyone know a way to map an array of complex types when indexing data using elastic4s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elastic4s or the java client (currently) isn't smart enough to figure out that you have a nested sequence or array, but it would work if it was a nested java map (still a bit rubbish from the Scala point of view).

I think the best thing to do is use the new Indexable typeclass that was added in 1.4.13

So, given

```
case class AThing(UserName: String, Comment: String, Time: String)
```

Then create a type class and bring it into scope

```
implicit object AThingIndexable extends Indexable[AThing] {
  def json = ... create json here using Jackson or similar which will handle nested sequences properly
}
```

Then you should be able to do:

```
client.execute { index into "myIndex/AThings" source aThing }
```

It's not quite as automatic as using the DocumentMap but gives you more control.

See a unit test [here](https://github.com/sksamuel/elastic4s/blob/master/src/test/scala/com/sksamuel/elastic4s/CommonQueryTest.scala) with it in action

Comment: thanks. 

Pity its not supported out of the box. I'll give this a try though, as it does seem to give me the best way to control the data.

Comment: Easy enough to add a JsonIndexable that does it for you as a helper trait, could add that and PR it ?

Comment: thanks would be great. 

Would that approach all it to detect internally nested types as well, if I make then JsonIndexable. Or am I misunderstanding what the JsonIndexable is going to do?

Comment: Yes it would detect all because it will leverage Jacksons support for creating nested json.

Comment: thanks @monkjack excellent. so it would in effect make an index request to elasticsearch which would look like this in json:

`{
    "Id": "some_string_id",
    "Things": [
       {"UserName"; "some_user_string", "Comment": "some_comment_string", "Time": "2015-03-31"},
       {"UserName"; "some_user_string_b", "Comment": "some_comment_string_b", "Time": "2015-03-31"}
    ]
 }`

Comment: Yes that's right. You can add that and do a PR if you want.

Comment: Might be easier if you take on that. I am not all that confident with either Scala or Java at the minute. If that's possible, will be implementing it the first way you suggested first and then can move it once the client has been updated.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to create index in elastic4s. I assume you did this.

```
 client.execute {
  create index "myIndex" mappings (
    "AThings" as(
      "UserName" typed StringType,
      "Comemnt" typed StringType,
      "Time" typed StringType,
      )
    )
}
```

if you create this index, then you can put case class into this directly.

```
val aThings = AThings("username","comment","time")
client.execute {index into "myIndex/AThings" doc aThings}
```

Comment: cheers @mhmtnlr I can't create the index via elastic4s instead it is created elsewhere within the whole application. Does it have to be done via elastic4s for the client to pick it up?

Also the index that is created would the ThingsThatHappened index within the example. the AThings would be an array field within the ThingsThatHappened index. Hopefully that makes sense.